# Internet access on Android device behind proxy with authentication

Tags: android, proxy, https

I am unable to connect to the Internet through android emulator 2.2 which is behind a proxy that requires proxy authentication.

Searched a lot over the Internet to find a proper solution but none of them are working for me.

I am running the emulator on a Ubuntu machine.

Situation:
I have an application which is designed to run on both ubuntu(linux) and android.

This application has a feature to connect to internet by providing proxy details and it connects properly when run on ubuntu after providing correct details. however this fails to connect through the emulator.
Even the web browser on the emulator doesn't connect to internet. Doing some changes in APN settings, it atleast gave me a webpage saying that the ISA server needs authentication, but never got any popup requesting to enter those details.

By applying -debug-proxy flag to emulator, the logs showed that it is trying to connect to the requested proxy server, but the server is challenging with authentication and none of the applications seem to get a chance to fill in this details and hence failing. This is what is happening with my application.

Does anyone have any clue why this could be happening and how i can resolve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

P.S. This is happening on actual android devices as well, so it may not be the problem of just the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Puneet ... Do as viv said and along with this give proxy address in its IP format instead of giving its DNS name. I have read some where that it is having problem in resolving DNS name.

Comment: Nopes.. Just tested it by providing, but the browser still keeps saying the same old thing. "407 proxy authorization required".

Comment: BTW, even with FQDN, it gave me the same error, so i guess it had resolved the server IP address properly. :(

Comment: I hope this link will help you  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5508

Comment: Thanks for the link but that didn't help either. People kept saying it should work, but the solution might work with proxy alone and not with proxy requiring authentication. :(

Comment: Puneet... I tried this in my office under the proxy and got succeeded.You double check the given 'Proxy Address'(IP address), Port, Domain name,UserId,password. You might be knowing this but want to tell you this,you should give the username as '<Domainname>/<username>'

Comment: Okay.. The username part... i didn't try this combination. Can try this tomorrow. Worth giving a try. :) However, just got to know from my company that the authentication is bit stricter, so i might not be able to get through this as well.. lets see. :) thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if I'm wrong but I think Puneet is talking about wifi connection. So the solution is not to configure an APN as it's for mobile networks. I got the same problem and I'm still searching for a solution...

Comment: You are right.. I was talking about WiFi. And I still haven't got a solution for this as well.. Had to get hold of people at my organization to bypass the proxy for the device :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple method by which you can get internet access on the device but only for browsing. Except the browser no other apps will have access to internet. You can find detailed information on http://androidproxy.blogspot.in/2011/01/setting-up-proxy.html.

In order to get the IP address just ping the proxy server in your organisation. By default the port is 8080.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Proxy Manager application to connect to internet from behind a authenticated proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Go to setings -> wireless and networks -> Mobile networks -> Access point name.
If you see any entry here, edit it's settings

Comment: I did go there, changed already present entry ( telkila ), even tried creating a new one, but none of these worked for me. If the proxy details were not set in any of the entries in APN settings, web browser kept showing that the page was getting loaded but never actually did, but if the proxy details were given ( even with the username/password ), it immediately showed a page saying the server needs authentication. Don't know where else do i have to provide the details.

Comment: sooooo if you already set ip, port, username, password and it's still not working, then some one wiser than me will be able to solve it........ god bless you......

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but just for people asking the same question, I did connect from my phone in proxy network that required authentication by using the Autoproxy app that is now in the android market: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mgranja.autoproxy_lite&feature=search_result&rdid=com.mgranja.autoproxy_lite&rdot=1&pli=1

Answer (score 0):

if you use webview, you can override onReceivedHttpAuthRequest method of webviewclient when set it.

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view,HttpAuthHandler handler,String host, String realm) {
            handler.proceed("username", "password");
        }
        });
```